# Enable permanent vertical and horizontal scroll bars

Tags: 14.04, scrolling

I am facing a problem and it is in Ubuntu (14.04) permanent scroll bar is not there but it appears when you move the mouse pointer to right most side or bottom most side. But it is very difficult to use and lately it takes too much to appear and sometimes it doesn't appear at all and so i have to close the application and reopen it. So i want to ask how to enable permanent scroll bars on right side and bottom most side. I am sure many people must have faced this problem before me. Thanks.

P.S: By permanent i mean scroll bars should be visible all the time.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can change scrollbar-mode with help of **`gsettings`**:

1. By default scrollbar is `overlay-auto` (to get current setting type following command):

   ```
   gsettings get com.canonical.desktop.interface scrollbar-mode
   ```

   [image: Overlay Scrollbar Mode]
2. You can set `normal` mode of scrollbar as follows:

   ```
   gsettings set com.canonical.desktop.interface scrollbar-mode normal
   ```

   [image: Normal Scrollbar Mode]

Images from [Unixmen](https://www.unixmen.com/disable-overlay-scrollbars-ubuntu-14.04-quick-tip/).

Comment: Thanks it worked, but will i have to type it every time i start my computer?

Comment: @RolenKoh No it will change permanently.